# How do I replace the merge tool in Visual Studio/TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Please, someone tell me that there is some way to replace the Merge Tool in TFS. I've already swapped out their diff tool with my preferred tool.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's "easy". See this [list of common diff/merge tool configurations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx).

(You can even use merge tools that *work*!)

Comment: I've been using TortoiseMerge with TFS for so long I can't even recall what the default merge tool looks like.

Comment: woohoo! awesome!  got them both working (I'm a kdiff3 fan myself)

Comment: ExamDiff and ExamDiff Pro; %1 %2 -nh -dn1:%6 -dn2:%7 <http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_versioncontrol.asp> but add -z:%4

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeyondCompare or Araxis Merge for code comparison and merging.  Both are paid commercial applications, but integrate well with Visual Studio environment.